# Check for populated columns and delete values based on hierarchy?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe (very simplified version below):

```
d = {'col1': [1, '', 2], 'col2': ['', '', 3], 'col3': [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need to loop through the dataframe and check how many columns are populated per row. If the row has just one column populated, then I can continue onto the next row. If however, the column has more than one **non-NaN** value, I need to make all the columns into NaNs apart from one, based on some hierarchy.

For example, let's say the hierarchy is:

1. col1 is the most important
2. col2 second etc.

Therefore, if there were two or more columns with data and one of them happened to be column 1, I would drop all other column values, otherwise I would defer to check if col2 has a value etc and then repeat for the next row.

I have something like this as an idea:

```
nrows = df.shape[0]

for index in range(0, nrows):
   print(index)
   #check is the row has only one column populated
   if (df.iloc[[index]].notna().sum() == 1):
      continue
   #check if more than one column is populated for that row
   elif (df.iloc[[index]].notna().sum() >= 1):
       if (index['col1'].notna() == True):
          df.loc[:, df.columns != 'col1'] == 'NaN'
   #continue down the hierarchy
```

but this is not correct as it gives True/False for every column and cannot read it the way I need.

Any suggestions very welcome! I was thinking of creating some sort of key, but feel there may be a more simply way to get there with the code I already have?

*Edit:
Another important point which I should have included is that my index is not integers - it is unique identifiers which look something like this: '123XYZ', which is why I used range(0,n) and reshaped the df.*

Answer (score 1):

For the example dataframe you gave I don't think it would change after applying this algorithm so I didn't test it thoroughly, but something like this should work:

```
import numpy as np
heirarchy = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
inds = df.isna().sum(axis=1)
inds = inds[inds >= 2].index

for i in inds:
    for col in heirarchy:
        if not pd.isna(df.iloc[[i]][col]).all():
            tmp = df.iloc[[i]][col]
            df.iloc[[i]] = np.nan
            df.iloc[[i]][col] = tmp
```

Note I'm assuming that you actually mean `nan` and not the empty string like you have in your example. If you want to look for empty strings then `inds` and the if statement would change above

I also think this should be faster than what you have above since it's only  looping through the rows with more than 1 `nan` values.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response, this was a much more elegant way of solving the problem. I just have one follow up which is causing issues in my code (my apologies I probably should have included in the question itself): I have an index that is not numbers, it looks something like '123XYZ', it is an identifier. Is there a way of modifying to account for this? As currently it will not recognise the index as it is not integers. Thanks!!

Comment: The easiest thing in my opinion would be to just run `df = df.reset_index()` but I'm not sure if you'd want to do that